# Is "doggu cheese" really Japanese, or slang in Japanese?

Tags: english-to-japanese, slang, japanese-to-english, comedy

In this part of this funny video: https://youtu.be/eXpyr0aVkHM?t=1159

The girl says "mother talk dog cheese" in English, trying to translate "My mother told me that it was cheese for the dog", and then the teacher corrects her in a funny manner by pretending to be a caveman or similar who says: "Mother talk doggu cheese".

Only he says the first two words ("mother" and "talk") in Japanese, and apparently says the "dog cheese" as "doggu cheese", which doesn't look like Japanese to me. It sound like English spoken by a Japanese person, or like a joke. But what confuses me is that he uses "real" Japanese (as far as I can tell, being as far from an expert in Japanese as one gets) in the first part of the sentence.

My question is: was this intentionally mixing English in Japanese for comedic effect, or is "doggu" really "dog" in Japanese, and "cheese" or "cheesu" acceptable to mean "cheese"?

Comment: Both ドッグ (doggu) and チーズ (chīzu) are [gairaigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gairaigo_and_wasei-eigo_terms) that are listed in every *Japanese* dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Cheese was introduced to Japan from outisde relatively recently, and so there is no native Japanese word for it. The English word was borrowed, as closely as Japanese can phonetically manage: チーズ *chiizu*.

Dogs, however, have been in Japan for centuries, and thus there's a Japanese word for them with no connection to the English word, 犬 *inu*. This character is also read *ken* in some words, a borrowing from the mediaeval Chinese reading, much like how we have both 'dog' and 'canine'.

However, if there were such a thing as 'dog cheese' that were a specific type of cheese, it would probably enter Japanese as 'doggu chiizu' rather than 'inu no chiizu' or anything. The man in the video kept it as 'dog cheese' to get across exactly what she'd just said to her - you probably wouldn't think 'dog cheese' meant 'cheese for the dog', would you?